# Tomcat Process occupying lot of Memory in UNIX BOX, how to reduce

Tags: unix, tomcat, process

I am using a play framework webapplication calling webservices, all these applications are deployed in one tomcat/apache server, when in production box, multiple process are started for tomcat which are occupying same MEM% which can be verified by top command. When the server is just started there are around 15 process which occupy 22% MEM (800m RES) and when the application is hit then the number of process increase to around 30-35 process.

As you can see the RES (Resident memory usage) is 880MB to 1.2 Gig, While the maximum memory allotted to tomcat is 256 MB using, -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Totally there are 3 web-application wars and 3 service wars deployed in this tomcat instance

PLEASE EXPLAIN HOW CAN I REDUCE THE MEMORY USAGE AND PROCESS FOR THIS APPLICATION???

AFTER START OF SERVER

top - 01:33:42 up 59 days, 1 min, 11 users,  load average: 4.76, 4.49, 3.29
Tasks: 1496 total,   1 running, 1493 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
Cpu(s): 31.3%us,  1.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 64.8%id,  1.0%wa,  0.2%hi,  0.8%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3759600k total,  3707492k used,    52108k free,    57912k buffers
Swap:  6313480k total,  3353744k used,  2959736k free,   155216k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
23070 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23071 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23072 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   3:29.07 java
23073 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:06.84 java
23074 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:06.98 java
23075 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:28.86 java
23076 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.04 java
23077 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.16 java
23078 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23079 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:55.73 java
23080 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:52.07 java
23081 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23082 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.12 java
23083 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23085 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23647 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23883 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23885 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23887 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
23893 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
24114 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
24122 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
24123 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
24126 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
24354 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
24375 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
24778 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
24843 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25059 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25069 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.04 java
25070 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25071 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:02.62 java
25072 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.86 java
25073 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.40 java
25076 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25077 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25078 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25079 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25080 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25559 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25560 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25561 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
25562 resoluti  20   0 1330m 931m 9316 S    0 25.4   0:00.00 java
17792 resoluti  20   0 86728 6376 1716 S    1  0.2   2:06.83 python
17793 resoluti  20   0 86728 6376 1716 S    0  0.2   0:00.04 python
17794 resoluti  20   0 86728 6376 1716 S    0  0.2   0:07.62 python
25340 resoluti  20   0  2868 1840  768 R    1  0.0   0:01.02 top
17791 resoluti  20   0 13724 1428 1428 S    0  0.0   0:00.14 python

Comment: Could you post the complete command line call of any of those java process? (# ps auxwww | grep java)

Comment: "jps -mv" makes it a lot easier to get that info, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Tomcat issue, but a (Oracle) JVM one. MaxPermSize sets the size of the *permanent* generation used for class loading, and then there's the heap which is normally larger. And this (plus native memory) is what uses the remaining memory.

See for example [this blog post](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/01/the-java-memory-architecture-1-act/)